# Change dynamically css class

Tags: css, jsf

Imagine that i have the following code:

```
<a:repeat value="#{bean.getList()}" var="x" >
   <li class="la">
      <span>
        <img src="#{bean.getThumbImageUrl(x)}"/>
       </span>
   </li>
</a:repeat>
```

I'm receiving a List of elements on bean.getList(). For each element, i'm getting it's image and print it. On the `<li>` tag, i'm defining a specific class. What i need it's to apply a different class to the last element of bean.getList().

Does anyone knows how to do it?

Thanks

Comment: What JSF libraries/frameworks are you using? What view technology (JSP/Facelets)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found the solution:

`<a:repeat value="#{bean.getList()}" var="x" rowKeyVar="row">
   <li class="#{row==<numberOfElements>?'lala':''}">
      <span>
        <img src="#{bean.getThumbImageUrl(x)}"/>
       </span>
   </li>
</a:repeat>`

Thanks for your help Kamil Szot

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use :dataList instead of :repeat to conditionally output something (class) for the last element, like in the following googled piece of code?

```
<t:dataList rowCountVar="rowCount" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">
  <h:outputText value="," rendered="#{(rowCount-1)!=rowIndex}"> 
</t:dataList>
```